# Como remover %3F entre outros do resultado?

Tags: javascript

Esse é minha primeira tentativa com programação, eu vi em um site um link que ao colocar nos favoritos serviria pra baixar um vídeo do youtube so que em formato mp3, porem n funcionava, ao fazer tentativas entendi o porque e tentei consertar, consegui fazer parcialmente pois no resultado aparece os simbolos em forma d codigo e eu n consigo fazer nada pra remover ele

```html
javascript:(function() {if (location.href.indexOf('youtube.com') > -1) {window.open('http://youtubeplaylist-mp3.com/download/index/' + encodeURIComponent(location.href) .replace("https", "") .replace("youtube", "") .replace("www.", "") .replace(".com", "") .replace("watch", "") .replace(/[%3A]/, '') .replace("", "") .replace("", ""));} else {alert('So funciona no youtube carambola');}})();
```

obs: eu sei que tem alguns comandos sem utilização ai mas essa é uma versão bem inicial e tem umas coisas so de testes que eu não acho que estejam influenciando

obss: fazendo isso pelo chrome (não sei se tem diferença mas achei que seria bom comentar)

obsss: eu inicialmente fiz um post no stackoverflow americano, link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526572/how-to-remove-3f-and-others-from-the-result-of-my-first-code (caso alguem queira ver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função: decodeURIComponen. Segue um exemplo simples:

```js
var texto = "%3F%3F%3F";
alert(decodeURIComponent(texto));
```